# How to test if the Gsuite user is allow to use the addon, or if is a Superadmin

Tags: google-apps-script

hello I'm trying to put a condition on a google addon for spreadsheet.
the condition is that the user who downloads the addon and tries to use it, has to be necessarily Superadmin, or gsuite administrator.
I had this idea but it only works correctly if you are superadmin, because if you are not you do not have access to AdminDirectory.

Any suggestions?

```js
function usertestpermisions()
{ 
  var permisions = AdminDirectory.Roles.list('my_customer')
  var permisionseaker =  permisions.items[0].isSuperAdminRole
  if (permisionseaker=true)
  {
    //var uia = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    //uia.alert("Great you are Gsuite superuser you can use all of this addons");
    showSidebar()
  }
  else
  {
    var uia = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    uia.alert("you need to be a superuser to make this work");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using some `try/catch` blocks.

```
function usertestpermisions()
{ 
  try{
    AdminDirectory
  } catch(e){
    Logger.log(e.message);
    Logger.log('Advanced Google Services for Admin Directory API must be enabled');
    return
  }

  try{
    var permisions = AdminDirectory.Roles.list('my_customer');
  } catch(e){
    Logger.log(e.message);
    Logger.log('You are either not in a Domain or are not a super user');
    return
  }

  var permisionseaker =  permisions.items[0].isSuperAdminRole
  if (permisionseaker=true)
  {
    //var uia = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    //uia.alert("Great you are Gsuite superuser you can use all of this addons");
    showSidebar()
  }
  else
  {
    var uia = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    uia.alert("you need to be a superuser to make this work");
  }
}
```

Comment: Tks i will try this.