# Check if user exists with AdminDirectory

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have a Sheet with a list of emails, and I want to create an account for emails that do not have one.
So I check with

```
function getUserFromEmail(email) {
    return user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(email)
}
```

but I get this error if user does not exists, and the script then stops :

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to directory.users.get failed with error: Resource Not Found: userKey

Do you have an idea on how I can make the error not blocking ?

Comment: Enclose your `AdminDirectory.Users.get()` in a `try...catch` block. You can find usage info for `try...catch` on MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: I was pretty sure I tried that, but I just did it again and it works. Thanks @TheAddonDepot, maybe you want to write an answer ?

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to test if the Gsuite user is allow to use the addon, or if is a Superadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53784823/1595451)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this for documentation purposes.

As suggested by [TheAddonDepot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66448549/check-if-user-exists-with-admindirectory/66528174#comment117473356_66448549), use [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) in order to handle situations in which the user is not found:

```
function getUserFromEmail(email) {
  try {
    return user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(email);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }  
}
```

Comment: But why it is going in catch, it should return user as null, instead of exception.

Comment: @AmayKulkarni Not really, this API method throws an exception if the user is not found.